# std::less<> not working with my std::map

Tags: c++, stl, std

I wanted to make a map with my own struct 'Point2' as key, however I am getting errors and I don't know what's causing it, since I declared an 'operator<' for the Point2 struct.

**Code:**

```
std::map<Point2, Prop*> m_Props_m;
std::map<Point2, Point2> m_Orders;

struct Point2
{
    unsigned int Point2::x;
    unsigned int Point2::y;

Point2& Point2::operator= (const Point2& b)
    {
        if (this != &b) {
            x = b.x;
            y = b.y;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    bool Point2::operator== (const Point2& b)
    {
        return ( x == b.x && y == b.y);
    }

    bool Point2::operator< (const Point2& b)
    {
        return ( x+y < b.x+b.y );
    }

    bool Point2::operator> (const Point2& b)
    {
        return ( x+y > b.x+b.y );
    }
};
```

**Error:**

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Point2' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>c:\testing\project\point2.h(34): could be 'bool Point2::operator <(const Point2 &)'
1>while trying to match the argument list '(const Point2, const Point2)'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(124) : while compiling class template member function 'bool std::less<_Ty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Point2
1>          ]
```

Can anyone see what's causing the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::map` expects a const version of `operator <`:

```
// note the final const on this line:
bool Point2::operator< (const Point2& b) const
{
    return ( x+y < b.x+b.y );
}
```

It doesn't make sense to have non-const versions of `operator==`, `operator>`, those should be `const` as well.

As ildjarn points out below, this is a clear case where you can implement these operators as free functions instead of member functions.  Generally, you should prefer these operators as free functions unless they *need* to be member functions.  Here's an example:

```
bool operator<(const Point2& lhs, const Point2& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.x + lhs.y) < (rhs.x + rhs.y);
}
```

Comment: Better yet, they shouldn't be defined as class members at all, but rather as free functions...

Comment: agreed.  Free functions are more appropriate in this specific example, but I was just posting the answer to help the OP.

Comment: Not criticizing your answer, just making an observation. :-]

Answer (score 3):

The `operator<` should be defined as `const`, in fact so should your other comparison operators, and in general, any method that doesn't mutate its class:

```
bool Point2::operator== (const Point2& b) const
{
    return ( x == b.x && y == b.y);
}

bool Point2::operator< (const Point2& b) const
{
    return ( x+y < b.x+b.y );
}

bool Point2::operator> (const Point2& b) const
{
    return ( x+y > b.x+b.y );
}
```